# Podman pod disappears after a few days, but process is still running and listening on a given port

Tags: rhel, podman, rhel8

I am running an Elasticsearch container as Podman pod using `podman play kube` and a `yaml` definition of a pod. Pod is created, cluster of three nodes is created and everything works as expected. But: Podman pod dies after a few days of staying idle.

Podman `podman ps` command says:

```
ERRO[0000] Error refreshing container af05fafe31f6bfb00c2599255c47e35813ecf5af9bbe6760ae8a4abffd343627: error acquiring lock 1 for container af05fafe31f6bfb00c2599255c47e35813ecf5af9bbe6760ae8a4abffd343627: file exists
ERRO[0000] Error refreshing container b4620633d99f156bb59eb327a918220d67145f8198d1c42b90d81e6cc29cbd6b: error acquiring lock 2 for container b4620633d99f156bb59eb327a918220d67145f8198d1c42b90d81e6cc29cbd6b: file exists
ERRO[0000] Error refreshing pod 389b0c34313d9b23ecea3faa0e494e28413bd15566d66297efa9b5065e025262: error retrieving lock 0 for pod 389b0c34313d9b23ecea3faa0e494e28413bd15566d66297efa9b5065e025262: file exists
POD ID        NAME               STATUS   CREATED     INFRA ID      # OF CONTAINERS
389b0c34313d  elasticsearch-pod  Created  1 week ago  af05fafe31f6  2
```

What's weird is that the process is still listening if we try to find the process id listening on port 9200 or 9300:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN      1328607/containers-
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN      1328607/containers-
```

The process ID that is hanging (and making the process still listening is):

```
user+ 1339220  0.0  0.1  45452  8284 ?        S    Jan11   2:19 /bin/slirp4netns --disable-host-loopback --mtu 65520 --enable-sandbox --enable-seccomp -c -e 3 -r 4 --netns-type=path /tmp/run-1002/netns/cni-e4bb2146-d04e-c3f1-9207-380a234efa1f tap0
```

The only actions I do to the pod is regular: `podman pod stop`, `podman pod rm` and `podman play kube` that is starting pod.

What can be causing such strange behaviour of Podman? What may be causing the lock not to be released properly?

System information:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.3 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.3"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8.3:GA"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.3
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.3"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.3 (Ootpa)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.3 (Ootpa)
```

`Podman` version:

```
podman --version
podman version 2.2.1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The workaround that worked for me is to add this configuration file from the Podman repository [1] under */usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/* and */etc/tmpfiles.d/*, in this way we are preventing the removal of Podman temporary files from /tmp directory [2]. As stated in [3], additionally CNI leaves Network information in */var/lib/cni/networks* when the system crashes or containers do not shut down properly. This behaviour has been fixed in the latest Podman release [4] and it happens when using rootless Podman.

### Workaround

First, check the runRoot default directory set for your Podman rootless user:

```
podman info | grep runRoot
```

Create the temporary configuration file:

```
sudo vim /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/podman.conf
```

Add the following content, replacing /tmp/podman-run-* by your default runRoot directory. E.g. If your output is /tmp/run-6695/containers then use: x /tmp/run-*

```
# /tmp/podman-run-* directory can contain content for Podman containers that have run
# for many days. This following line prevents systemd from removing this content.
x /tmp/podman-run-*
x /tmp/containers-user-*
D! /run/podman 0700 root root
D! /var/lib/cni/networks
```

Copy the temporary file from /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d to /etc/tmpfiles.d/

```
sudo cp -p /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/podman.conf /etc/tmpfiles.d/
```

After you have done all the steps according to your configuration, the error should disappear.

References

1. https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/master/contrib/tmpfile/podman.conf
2. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1888988#c9
3. https://github.com/containers/podman/commit/2e0a9c453b03d2a372a3ab03b9720237e93a067c
4. https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/8241

Comment: I've propagated the change to servers, let's see how it helps. Hard to test if the issue is showing itself after a few days. ;) Thank you!

Comment: For anyone taking this fix as a solution, make sure that `runRoot` corresponds to the directory that you are setting to be ignored in `tmpfiles.d`, in my case I had to change `/tmp/podman-run-*` to `/tmp/run-*` (e.g. `/tmp/run-1001`). Consult `podman info`: `runRoot: /tmp/run-1002/containers`. Relevant Podman issue: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/9663

Comment: The workaround solution by @llopisga seems not working. We still see same error even after copying podman.conf to  /etc/tmpfiles.d/ERRO[0000] Error refreshing container 28d7f360049bd3c3bd7f55baf78af3e11e3baf9ad489586899c928767f51cb2d: error acquiring lock 0 for container 28d7f360049bd3c3bd7f55baf78af3e11e3baf9ad489586899c928767f51cb2d: file exists